How can I disable/prevent users from installing Windows Subsystem for Linux via GPO?
My security team is forcing us to disable WSL, and in my research I've seen methods using Powershell, Registry keys, and Intune, but none of those options are available, or they are unacceptable to security. I need a way to disable WSL if it is present, and keep users from installing WSL or enabling it in the "Add or Remove Windows Features" menu.
I've seen one suggestion of disabling the LxssManager service in Computer Config -> Policies -> Windows Settings -> Security Settings -> System Services, but LxssManager isn't present there.
Co-Pilot suggested a path of Computer Configuration -> Administrative Templates -> Windows Components -> Windows Subsystem for Linux, which doesn't exist either, and I can't find any reference to online so I'll assume it's an AI hallucination.
Co-Pilot also suggested using a Software Restriction Policy to disallow the path "C:\System32\wsl.exe", which seems like it could block the executable itself, but doesn't stop someone from installing it in the first place.

I'm fine if the answer is "You can't", I just need someone who knows this better than I do to tell me so.

Why do your users have admin rights? AFAIK that is required to enable it in the Add or Remove Windows Features. If they have admin rights, disabling WSL won't really matter security wise; WSL gives no new capabilities...

Security's view is that since we have some users [IT folks] who have admin accounts, they assume everyone has admin rights as far as their concerns go. I know it's dumb, but I want them to stop banging on my door and if this gets them to leave me alone, I'll roll with it.

Tell them that they are dumb. If they repeat banging your door, repeat with louder voice that they are dumb. If they keep coming, quit job and look for a better one. ;-) Or remove admin rights for everybody (even for IT folks), effectivly locking out everyone and watch the world burn.

Thanks for the unsolicited career advice. Can anyone actually answer my question instead of complaining about the situation I'm in? I can do that well enough on my own.
